# add text formatting to specific texts in excel generated email

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using excel vba to set certain texts in the email body bold

here is my code

```
xFirstName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2")
xMembershipDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G2")

On Error Resume Next
Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)

xMailBody = "Hello " & xFirstName & vbNewLine & _
"Your membership has been verified last " & xMembershipDate & vbNewLine & _
"" & vbNewLine & _
"Thank you."
```

I'd like to set xFirstName and xMembershipDate to appear as bold in the email body. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to use HTML tags.

```
    xFirstName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2")
    xMembershipDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G2")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With xOutMail
        .HTMLBody = "<p>Hello <b>" & xFirstName & "</b></p>" & _
                    "<p>Your membership has been verified last <b>" & xMembershipDate & "</b></p>" & _
                    "" & vbNewLine & _
                    "<p>Thank you.</p>"
    End With
```